# Node.js: Winston: Can I add default meta data to all log messages

Tags: node.js, flatiron.js

I'm using [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) in Node.js for logging. I know I can add metadata individually to each log message but is there a way to specify a default set of metadata that'll be added to every log message (such as the app name) as I don't want to specify it every time I need to send a log message.

Comment: There is now a documented way to do this, see my answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, but you can definitely add it yourself - here's how:

First, set up your logger like you normally would. For example:

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
            "exitOnError" : true,
            "transports" : [
                new (winston.transports.Console)({ "colorize" : true, "level" : "silly", "silent" : false, "handleExceptions" : false }),
            ]
        });
```

Then override the log() method (this is always called by the level methods - `logger.foo()` actually calls `logger.log('foo')`.)

```
logger.log = function(){
  var args = arguments;
  if(args[2]) args[3] = args[2];
  args[2] = {
    "foo" : "bar"
  }
  winston.Logger.prototype.log.apply(this,args);
}
```

All I'm doing above is making it so when `logger.log()` is called, it instead calls the above method, which adds the metadata (in this case, an object containing a `foo` key). Then it calls winston's Logger.log method from the proper context.

The above code would be in a module you create, at the bottom just export the logger:

`module.exports = logger;`

and import the logger module instead of the winston module in your sub classes.

`var logger = require('./logger.js');`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Note: this will overwrite any metadata you specify in the log statement. You can use underscore's `_.defaults()` to augment it, or you could add a check for args[2] and not overwrite it if it exists to get around this.

Comment: Instead of overwriting the arguments, just append them:

    logger.log = function(){
          var args = arguments;
          if(args[2]) {
            args[2].foo = "bar"
          }
          winston.Logger.prototype.log.apply(this,args);
        }

Comment: @Jesse: There is now a supported way to do this, with `rewriter`

Comment: @DrakaSAN winston v3 seems to remove the possibility to mutate the metadata cf https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1140

Answer (score 49):

*For Winston v2 (see comments)*

There are now [`rewriters`](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#filters-and-rewriters).

For example, the below will add a property `app` to every metadata going through this logger.

```js
    logger.rewriters.push(function(level, msg, meta) {
      meta.app = 'myApp';
      return meta;
    });
```

You can also declare it when building the logger:

```js
    new (winston.Logger)({
            level: config.log[file].level,
            rewriters: [
                (level, msg, meta) => {
                    meta.app = 'myApp';
                    return meta;
                }
            ],
            transports: [
                /*your transports*/
            ]
    });
```

Comment: winston v3 seems to remove the possibility to mutate the metadata. It means that @Jesse is the preferred solution for winston v3 & + if you want to add metadata. If the output log is a string and not JSON, a custom format can do the job (cf github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1140)

Comment: @ThierryAbaléa: Thanks for the tip, I ll try out the custom format solution, and update my answer accordingly

Comment: The release Winston v3 does allow mutating the metadata, and the issue mentioned by Thierry helped to get an example added to the migration guide and was how I found it too. I have added another answer with the new way.

Answer (score 43):

For Winston v3:

```
const addAppNameFormat = winston.format(info => {
  info.appName = "My Program";
  return info;
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: winston.format.combine(
    addAppNameFormat(),
    winston.format.json()
  ),
transports: [new winston.transports.Console()]
});

logger.warn('Danger Will Robinson!');
// {"message":"Danger Will Robinson!","level":"warn","appName":"My Program"}
```

See: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/HEAD/UPGRADE-3.0.md#migrating-filters-and-rewriters-to-formats-in-winston3

Answer (score 36):

There is now (8/20/19) a property `defaultMeta` that is passed to `createLogger` that will inject the meta you specify to every log.

```js
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
  transports: [
    //
    // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
    // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
    //
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option with an output more like log4j(s):

There is a [documented](https://github.com/winstonjs/logform#label) `label` property which will add a label to the output (json or line):

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var winston = require('winston');
var path = require('path');
var baseDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

// SETUP WINSTON LOGGER
var container = new winston.Container();
container.add("exception", {
    console: {
        handleExceptions: true,
        timestamp: true,
        label: "EXCEPTION",
        colorize: true
    }
});
container.get("exception").exitOnError = false;
var keys = [];
    
module.exports = function(filename) {
    var label = path.relative(baseDir, filename);
    if (!_.contains(keys, label)) {
        container.add(label, {
            console: {
                handleExceptions: false,
                level: 'debug',
                timestamp: true,
                label: label,
                colorize: true
            }
        });
        keys.push(label);
    }
    var logger = container.get(label);
    logger.exitOnError = false;
    return logger;
};
```

And in the other modules require it like this:

```
var logger = require('./logger')(__filename);
```

Example output:

```
2014-07-23T07:05:27.770Z - info: [config/config.js] .......
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a way to add the github delivery ID to all my logs.

I use winston 3 and `defaultMeta` getters along with `express-http-context`

```
// logger.js 
const logger = (filename) => winston.createLogger({
    ...
    defaultMeta: {
        get deliveryId () { return httpContext.get('deliveryId'); },
        get deliveryEvent () { return httpContext.get('deliveryEvent'); },
        module: filename,
    },
    ...
});

module.exports = (fileName) => {
    return logger(fileName);
}
```

in my other modules:

```
// foo.js
const logger = require('./logger')(__filename)

module.exports = async(someInput) => {
    logger.debug('hello ' + someInput)
}
```

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1626#issuecomment-531142958

Comment: Combining the 'get' is NICE and also very useful because it turns the defaultMeta into a dynamic object

Answer (score 1):

I've found a better way using [util-extend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util-extend) based on what I read on [this blog](http://dhalsim.github.io/en/node.js/i-have-control/2015/11/13/nodejs-error-management-and-logging#demo). It will append the data in all cases, which I found useful for catching logger.info vs logger.log("info", message) and won't overwrite your other arguments.

```
logger.log = function(){
   var args = arguments;
   var level = args[0];

   var newArgs = {
        foo: "bar",
        baz: "abc"
   };
   var originalMeta = args[2] || {};
   args[2] = extend(originalMeta, newArgs);

   winston.Logger.prototype.log.apply(this,args);
};
```

Will output in the console and in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `winston@3x` , there are 2 levels of `metadata`, `default` and `child`

```
// logger.ts

const logger = createLogger({
  level:"info",
  defaultMeta: { app: "MyApp" },
  handleExceptions: true,
  format: format.combine(
    format.errors({ stack: true }),
    format.timestamp(),
    format.json()
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()],
});


export default function getLogger(childName = ""): Logger {
  if (!childName) {
    return logger;
  }
  return logger.child({ childName });
}
```

```
// some-where.ts

const logger = getLogger("OnEarth")
logger.info("dog - bark bark")
```

--------  output ------------

```
{
  ....
  level: "info",
  message: "dog - bark bark",
  app: "MyApp",
  childName: "OnEarth"
}
```